# How to jQuery bindings with a Backbone View

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a Backbone view, Inside that view there's an input that uses twitters typeahead plugin. My code works, but I'm currently doing the typeahead initialisation inside the html code and not in my Backbone code.

```
    TypeAhead.init('#findProcedure', 'search/procedures', 'procedure', 'name', function(suggestion){

    var source   = $("#procedure-row-template").html();

    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

    var context = {
        name: suggestion.name,
        created_at: suggestion.created_at,
        frequency: suggestion.frequency.frequency,
        urgency: suggestion.urgency.urgency,
        id: suggestion.id
    };

    var html    = template(context);

    AddRow.init("#procedure-table", html);

});
```

The code above is what works inside script tag.

But when I try taking to backbone it doesn't work.

What I'm trying in my BB code is:

```
    initialize: function(ob) {
    var url = ob.route;
    this.render(url);
    this.initTypeahead();
    this.delegateEvents();
},
```

And obviously inside the init function there's the code that works, but not in BB. What could be wrong ? Is this a correcto approach ?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like your `initTypeahead` is looking for a bunch of things directly in the current page so are those things on the page when you think they are?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15524641/3585500) from Derick Bailey about backbone and plugins.